# Is it safe to remove sysvinit package in Debian sid?

Tags: debian, upstart

Currently, I have some packages my own using `upstart`, they are working with the stable branch of Debian. I'm going to switch to sid/unstable, and then the warning comes:

```
WARNING: The following essential packages will be removed.
This should NOT be done unless you know exactly what you are doing
sysvinit
```

Is it safe to remove `sysvinit`?

P.S. It's a clean base system setup by

```
# debootstrap --variant=buildd sid /sid-root
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not safe.  It may be *possible*, if "you know exactly what you are doing", but just replacing sysvinit with upstart is probably going to create a huge mess in stable Debian releases.  There is work going on to make that possible in the future (squeeze release).